# Jenkins Git Publisher: timeout after 10min

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-web-app-service

**tl;dr:**
I run into a timeout during git push (Git Publisher plugin).
Is there a way to increase the timeout (default 10 minutes) ?

**More details:**
I use Jenkins to push a nightly build to Azure Web App. Web Apps are configured to run a `deploy.cmd` after all files are pushed. I modified this deploy.cmd so that the execution of this script takes > 10 minutes.
When I push from my local PC everything works fine.
But Jenkins closes connection after 10 minutes - which causes an abortion of the script-execution.
So is there a way to increase the 10min timeout limit of Jenkins Git Pubisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Git plugin does allow specifying a timeout for clone operations, the Git Publisher post-build action currently does not provide a way to configure the timeout.  As you've seen, it falls back to a default timeout value of 10 minutes.

However, you can change the default timeout of 10 minutes — though this will apply to all operations by the Git plugin that don't allow setting a timeout explicitly.

To do so, set the `org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut` [system property](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) to a value in minutes. For example, this would increase the timeout to 20 minutes:
`java -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut=20 -jar jenkins.war`
(or set it in `/etc/default/jenkins` or similar if running from a Linux package)

Note that you likely have to set this property on [both the master, and any agents](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22547?focusedCommentId=209912#comment-209912) where this timeout should apply.